# PHP static context refers to the wrong class

Tags: oop, ubuntu, nginx, php

---

I have some php code in a site that I'm trying to move to a different server (from development into production) similar to the following:

```
class test1 {

    static function make () {
        $object = static::maker(function( $params ) {
            return new static($params);
        });
        return $object;
    }

    protected static function maker ( $callable ) {
        $params = [/*...*/];
        return $callable( $params );
    }

}

class test2 extends test1 {

    function sayhi () {
        echo "Hello! from: ".get_called_class();
    }

}

$test = test2::make();
$test->sayhi();
```

My development environment is OSX 10.9 running php 5.5.17 and nginx with php-fpm, and my production environment is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS running php 5.5.11 and nginx with php-fpm.

on my development machine I get the expected result:

```
Hello! from: test2
```

but on the production server it throws an error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method test1::sayhi()
```

revealing that the static context is pointing to test1 which isn't expected.
The workaround I came up with is to call the function like this:

```
$class = get_called_class();
$object = static::maker(function( $params ) use ( $class ) {
    return new $class($params);
});
```

My question is: Why is it different between versions? And can someone shed some light on what's the expected behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question: late static bindings.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67774
http://php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php